# how can i change this to replace the 404 page error with a html page?

Tags: java, html, servlets, server, jetty

I have to change the 404 error page with a customed page from my html file.
I wrote this code but it doesn't work,  and/or I don't know how to use it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/rac");

        Server jettyServer = new Server(8080);
        context.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "./src/main/resources/index.html" });

        ErrorPageErrorHandler errorHandler = new ErrorPageErrorHandler();
        errorHandler.addErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND_404, "./src/main/resources/error.html");
        context.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

        // HTML
        DefaultServlet defaultServlet = new DefaultServlet();
        ServletHolder holderPwd = new ServletHolder("default", defaultServlet);
        holderPwd.setInitParameter("resourceBase", "./src/main/resources/index.html");
        context.addServlet(holderPwd, "/*");

        // SERVICES
        ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class,
                "/ajax/*");
        jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

        jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
                DiskServiceWS.class.getCanonicalName() + "," + RamServiceWS.class.getCanonicalName() + ","
                        + CpuServiceWS.class.getCanonicalName());

        jettyServer.setHandler(context);

        try {
            jettyServer.start();
            jettyServer.join();
        } finally {
            jettyServer.destroy();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which 404 error?  From Jetty? From your ServletContextHandler? or from your Jersey layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't indicated what kind of 404 error you are getting.

If the 404 from Jetty itself (not part of a context), then that's controlled by the `Server` level `ErrorHandler`.  (such as a GET request for `http://<machine>/foo/bar` in your scenario, as "/foo" is not part of your "/wac" context)

If the 404 from an error that flows back to the `ServletContextHandler`, then your existing `ErrorPageErrorHandler` is mostly correct.

The second parameter on `addErrorPage` is a URL path (relative to your declared Base Resource), not a filesystem path.

Example (assuming that `/error.html` is accessible via a web GET request):

```java
ErrorPageErrorHandler errorHandler = new ErrorPageErrorHandler();
errorHandler.addErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND_404, "/error.html");
context.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
```

Note: the URL path could point to a Servlet (yours, a jsp, a jersey endpoint, etc..) if you wanted, it doesn't have to be HTML.

If the 404 is from a JAX-RS / Jersey request, then there's specific handling in JAX-RS / Jersey to produce a valid 404 error response based on the incoming request details.

An example would be a REST client requesting a JSON resource, and Jersey producing a 404 response with a JSON body indicating the error details.

Other notes ...

```java
DefaultServlet defaultServlet = new DefaultServlet();
ServletHolder holderPwd = new ServletHolder("default", defaultServlet);
holderPwd.setInitParameter("resourceBase", "./src/main/resources/index.html");
```

Do not declare your `resourceBase` on your `DefaultServlet`, declare it on your `ServletContextHandler`.

```java
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/rac");
context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource("/path/to/my/base/directory"));
```

Also, a `resourceBase` is a fully qualified directory path (or URI), never a file, or a relative path.

And `setWelcomeFiles` are filenames or path relative URL locations to use if the incoming GET request is to a directory resource.

Example:

```java
context.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html", "welcome.html", "index.jsp" });
```

So that a request for say `http://<machine>/wac/` would result in actually serving `http://<machine>/wac/index.html` (if it exists).

This also applies to deep directory requests, such as `http://<machine>/wac/app/deps/scripts/jquery/` would result in serving the contents of `http://<machine>/wac/app/deps/scripts/jquery/index.html`